# Cakephp 2.5 subtract count from unset array operation

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePHp 2.5 and need to remove some results from the query:

```
$this->paginate = $paginate; 
$results = $this->paginate('services'); 
foreach($results as $key=>$data ) 
{ 
    if( empty( $dado['services']['service_id'] ) ) 
    { 
        unset($results[$key]); 
    }
```

The result count will keep the original count.

Is there a way to subtract, the paginate query count, when i do unset the query results?

Looking at the [Paginator class](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-PaginatorComponent.html) can not see if there is a property with the result count information.

Comment: is there a property i can manipulate to alter the count from the paginate query results

Comment: Working now, thank you ! this is the right aproach to paginate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't post-process the results of an sql call.

If you post-process the results of the sql call, unless the results fit in one page the count is always going to be inaccurate - because you'd be removing results from the current page, yet other results you *would* remove would still be present in the other pages - affecting the count.

### Make paginate return what you want

Instead, just make the database give you the results you want, and none you don't:

```
$this->paginate['conditions'] = ['service_id IS NOT NULL'];
$results = $this->paginate('services');
```

If service id can be null or 0, you can account for that using a greater-than comparison:

```
$this->paginate['conditions'] = ['service_id >' => 0];
$results = $this->paginate('services');
```